# Expires header based on dynamic Content-Type in nginx

Tags: nginx, http-headers, content-type, http-caching, expires-header

I have a PHP website where some content is user-generated. For example, users can upload photos that get resized and can be requested. I'd like to specify an `Expires` header (for caching) based on the MIME type (`Content-Type` response header) in my nginx configuration.

This is my current configuration (my host automatically adds `http{}` and `server{}`):

```
charset utf-8;

types {
    text/css            css;
    text/javascript     js;
}

gzip on;
gzip_types text/html text/css text/javascript application/json image/svg+xml;

location / {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite  .  /index.php last;
        break;
    }


    set $expire 0;

    if ($upstream_http_content_type = image/jpeg) { set $expire 1; }
    if ($upstream_http_content_type = image/png) { set $expire 1; }
    if ($upstream_http_content_type = image/gif) { set $expire 1; }
    if ($upstream_http_content_type = image/svg+xml) { set $expire 1; }
    if ($upstream_http_content_type = text/css) { set $expire 1; }
    if ($upstream_http_content_type = text/javascript) { set $expire 1; }

    if ($expire = 1) {
        expires max;
    }
}
```

This works for static files (like `.png` files — they get the right `Expires` header), but it has no effect on dynamically generated content from `index.php` (no `Expires` header at all). Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What are dynamics files? You mean dynamics files come when user upload real file (for example image) and your web app transfer it (for example resized) and send it back, it's a dynamic file, yes?

Comment: @emka86 I changed the question to clarify that part. I meant content that was generated dynamically by `index.php`.

Comment: I check your conf screenshot and from my side of view it's immpossible to work. You don't have any `root` directive so nginx doesn't even know where to start searching for any files. Next you are using `index.php` but nowhere is any `proxy_pass` or `fastcgi_pass` directives to redirect nginx request to some PHP application. Nginx by his own doesn't understand how to process `.php` files. Please check something of this two: http://kbeezie.com/nginx-configuration-examples/  or  http://wiki.nginx.org/FullExample

Comment: I know it's too late, but look at this answer. http://serverfault.com/a/733567/118284

Answer (score 1):

In your `location` block there is nowhere place when you pass request to php web app so I can suppose that you do it somewhere else, for example in `location` block like this one:

```
location /index.php {
   # your code
}
```

With your configuration when user request for a static file which exists then first `if` directive isn't calculated and everything goes well. Problems starts when user request for dynamic files then nginx enter your first `if` block:

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite  .  /index.php last;
    break;
}
```

And here what happend? You are using `last` flag with `rewrite` directive and what nginx's doc says about this?

*last - completes processing of current rewrite directives and restarts the process (including rewriting) with a search for a match on the URI from all available locations.*

According to this specification when file is dynamical you made a rewrite to `index.php` and execution leaves `if` block and even whole `location` block and following `if` block for checking `content-type` aren't even checked. I suppose it find then `location` for url `/index.php` and there you don't set `expires max`.

Do you understand this expalantion of your problem?

Resolution to this is too move/copy your sequential `if` block for checking `content-type` to place where your config pass execution to php web app (index.php) ... or remove `last` flag from `rewrite` directive if it doesn't make any other troubles.

Okey, so as I promised a little fix to your conf file: change your `location` block with this two:

```
location /index.php {
   if ($upstream_http_content_type ~ "(image/jpeg)|(image/png)|(image/gif)|(image/svg+xml)|(text/css)|(text/javascript)") {
      expires max;
   }
   if ($sent_http_content_type ~ "(image/jpeg)|(image/png)|(image/gif)|(image/svg+xml)|(text/css)|(text/javascript)") {
      expires max;
   }
}

location / {
   if ($upstream_http_content_type ~ "(image/jpeg)|(image/png)|(image/gif)|(image/svg+xml)|(text/css)|(text/javascript)") {
      expires max;
   }
   if ($sent_http_content_type ~ "(image/jpeg)|(image/png)|(image/gif)|(image/svg+xml)|(text/css)|(text/javascript)") {
      expires max;
   }
   try_files $uri /index.php =404;
}
```

First `location` block is for your `index.php` and dynamic response while second one is for static files. In second one we add header `expires max` as upstream header and as standard header (just to be sure). I use here one `if` block for all types you defined in your configuration with regex pattern match. At the end we use `try_files` directive which means if it is possible to get static file based on url it will be gained and in other way try url /index.php or just return with http 404. First location block is only for url `/index.php`.
I found nowhere in your config `root` directive which should point to root folder of your application. Try to add this also ([root doc](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#root)).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I partially understand the problem. However, this is the first time I'm working with nginx and I'm not experienced enough to come up with a solution. I've pasted my whole configuration in the question now; would you mind to take another look to see if you can see what I should change? Thanks again!

Comment: It's realy the whole conf? No more `location` blocks? Your app isn't working as you expect only for this issue with `expires`?

Comment: Yeah, this is all. My `index.php` reads the requested path and handles everything from there (that's why all requests for non-existing files/folders are rewritten to `index.php`). Works great, except for the `Expires` header.

The reason for handling most things in PHP is that the project not only runs on nginx, but also on Apache. For that reason I like to do as few as possible in the HTTP server configuration.

Comment: Okey, I will try to give you some answer which not only describe your problem but also fix it :)

Comment: Thanks for your update. If I remove the `location {}` block from my own config and paste in your code, the source code of `index.php` is outputted when browsing to `/` and other URLs (that normally get handled by `index.php`) get a 404. I tried moving some parts and changing some things, but I still can't get it to work. Maybe I should just handle this in PHP (although I'd prefer to let it be done by the web server)…

Comment: One thing I still don't understand. How nginx process your `index.php` file. Do you realy don't have any other place in your config where you use `index.php` url? Maybe some `include` directives which indicate other `.conf` files? You past your configuration but from my point this conf is useles and have no change to work if it is whole `server` block of your configuration :/

Comment: Here's a [screenshot](http://cl.ly/image/3Y0M0k0j1I1h) of the control panel of my host. As you can see my host automatically adds the `http` and `server` block, but they aren't doing other fancy things.

Comment: This one has a few answers: http://serverfault.com/questions/515501/add-expires-header-conditionally-based-on-mime-type-in-nginx

Comment: Fairly old question, but came across any way. You could have just added `<?php header("Cache-Control: private, max-age=8600"); ?>` for your dynamic content from within php, correct?